# Abrir arquivos que vão ser compartilhados entre várias funções, dentro ou fora das funções?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, arquivo

Seguinte, eu estou fazendo um programa que vou dividir entre o módulo de funções e a interface, e eu preciso usar arquivos nesse projeto(e não posso usar classes), acontece que eu preciso usar esses arquivos entre varias funções, umas que vão escrever neles, outras que vão apenas ler, etc. 
Aqui um pedaço do código:

```
arqProfessores = open("arqProfessores.txt","r+")
arqDisciplinas = open("arqDisciplinas.txt","r+")
arqAlunos = open("arqAlunos.txt","r+")
arqTurmas = open("arqTurmas.txt","r+")


def addProfessor(cpf, nome, departamento):
    if cpf not in arqProfessores:
    dicProfessor = {"Nome":nome, "Cpf":cpf, "Departamento":departamento}
    arqProfessores = open("arqProfessores.txt","a")
    arqProfessores.write(dicProfessor)
    arqProfessores.close()
    print("Professor cadastrado com sucesso.")
else:
    print("Erro de cadastro.\nEste professor já está cadastrado no 
sistema.")


def consultarProfessor(cpf):
    arqProfessores = open("arqProfessores.txt","r")
    if cpf in arqProfessores:
        dicProfessor = arqProfessores.read(cpf)          #definindo uma 
variavel para a chave do dicionario de professores
        for chave,elem in dicProfessor.items():
            print(chave + ": " + str(elem))
        arqProfessores.close()
else:
    print("Este professor não é funcionário desta faculdade.")
```

(a formatação não está assim)
Enfim, por exemplo, tem uma função que eu tenho que tenho que escrever no arquivo sem apagar o que ja está escrito por isso o "a" no arquivo, mas lá em cima eu abri como "r+", desculpem a ignorância, mas eu sou muito leigo quando o assunto é arquivo :/
O que vocês recomendam fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu tivesse que construir esse tipo de programa, eu faria com que a função devesse receber um objeto tipo arquivo, e usaria um 'gestor de contexto' (o `with`) nas funcionalidades principais do programa para deixar o código mais "lível". Um exemplo do que quero dizer:

```
def funcao(par1, par2, par3, arquivo):
    # fazer_coisas
    arquivo.write()


def funcao2(par1, par2, par3, arquivo):
    # fazer outras coisas
    arquivo.write()


def main():

    try:
        # abra os arquivos com o modo que se precisar
        with open('arquivo1', 'rw') as a, open('arq2', 'rw') as b:
            # coisas
            funcao(2, 3, 4, a)
            funcao2(2, 3, 4, b)
            # outras coisas

    except IOError as e:
        print('Operation failed: {erro}'.format(erro=e.strerror))
```

Tenha noção de que com o `with` não precisa fechar o arquivo. O próprio método `.__exit__`, que é executado quando o programa sai do `with` toma conta disso. Parte dessa resposta eu me baseei [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617034/how-can-i-open-multiple-files-using-with-open-in-python).